# Get correct values of mean of matrix rows

Tags: matrix, octave, mean

I have just started my journey with Octave - I got a huge data files which i have to deal with.

I am using a 3.8.2 version of Octave on Cygwin64 AND 3.8.2-3 Inofficial GNU Octave builds for Windows - my problem appears on both, so I assume it is my mistake rather than a bug.

Since I am not very good with this program, I got a problem with my data.

So, this is how it looks.

Every file of my data contains a structure, called datastr.

This is what it prints after

```
 >> whos
 Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name         Size                  Bytes  Class
   ==== ====         ====                  =====  =====
        datastr      1x1                   38084576  struct

Total is 1 element using 38084576 bytes
```

After printing the fields in the structure, I got this:

```
 >>struct_levels_to_print(0)
 >>datastr

 scalar structure containing the fields:

t0: 1x1 scalar
chanCount: 1x1 scalar
chanLabels: 1x7 cell
fs: 1x1 scalar
calibr: 1x7 matrix
data: 7x1360160 float matrix
```

What I am interested in, is the data, the float matrix, containing 7 rows, each having 1360160 columns.

This is how two first rows look (only seven columns posted, I quitted afterwards)

```
>>struct_levels_to_print(1)
>>datastr

Columns 1 through 7:
3.9899e+004  4.3311e+004  4.6618e+004  4.6773e+004  4.2841e+004  4.0228e+004  3.5909e+004
2.8070e+004  2.2204e+004  1.5375e+004  9.6730e+003  -8.2862e+004  -7.9456e+004 -7.6144e+004
```

I have extracted matrix from structure and added it to a variable:

```
 >> MyData = datastr.data
```

MyData variable is single class

```
>> whos
Variables in the current scope:

Attr Name         Size                     Bytes  Class
==== ====         ====                     =====  =====
     MyData       7x1360160             38084480  single
     datastr      1x1                   38084576  struct
```

Then I change format to long (And yes, I have tried NOT changing the format, the final result is the same)

```
>> format long
>> MyData
```

This is what happened to first two rows after this move (MyData still single):

```
39899  43311  46618  46773  42841  40228  35909
28070  22204  15375  96730  -82862  -79456 -76144
```

This isn't correct data (the dots and scientific notation are gone) - those are the same numbers, but not the same data. I think this is the problem, however there is more to that.

What I want to do, is to get mean for each row, separatly. That means, in the end, I should have 7 seperate means, each for one row of data.

I have searched the web and got this: I should type

```
>> M1 = mean(MyData,2)
```

which should get me mean of every single row in my float matrix.

However, the results are not quite what I was after:

```
M1 =

-91349216
-91482784
```

Those are mean values for 2 first rows. It is not correct (I have manually copied the data of first row to Excel and checked it).

Median prints similar, wrong values.

The funny part is that when I don't use *>>format long* code, Octave displays correct values (with dots and scientific 'e') but the result of *mean* is still wrong.

There are no empty "cells" in this matrix

I wasn't able to find an answer on the internet (mostly because I didn't know what question should I ask)

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? What should I type, to get the result I am looking for?

Thank you in advance for your support.

EDIT: I have added all lines of code (not much coding, really) that I am using.
The Data is real data (only shortened, since I don't want to post 1360160 columns)

EDIT2: 
Here is the link to one of my files. http://we.tl/mL6agFvssQ I chose the file with the data presented above and put it on WeTransfer. Perhaps there is yet another thing I just don't know.

Comment: You really should add your source code (how do you "MyData variable is single class") and try to create some artificial data which you can include here and show the problem. I guess you are converting your data to integer at some point.

Comment: All right - thank you. I will create some data similar to original and I will post codes, results etc.

Comment: Ok, I have edited all the codelines. Now it shows, step by step, what I do with this data. I do nothing more, since I tought getting mean of those rows in matrix is going to be sooooo simple, even for beginner. How wrong I was...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't undestand why you say "This isn't correct data (the dots and scientific notation are gone) - those are the same numbers, but not the same data."

```
3.9899e+004  4.3311e+004  4.6618e+004  4.6773e+004  4.2841e+004  4.0228e+004  3.5909e+004
2.8070e+004  2.2204e+004  1.5375e+004  9.6730e+003  -8.2862e+004  -7.9456e+004 -7.6144e+004
```

and

```
39899  43311  46618  46773  42841  40228  35909
28070  22204  15375  96730  -82862  -79456 -76144
```

are the same data, just another display format. You can force the above format with

```
format short e
```

I created a testcase from your question:

```
tmp = [39899  43311  46618  46773  42841  40228  35909;
    28070  22204  15375  96730  -82862  -79456 -76144];
datastr = struct ("data", single(tmp), "t0", 1.23);
struct_levels_to_print(0)
datastr
MyData = datastr.data
M1 = mean(MyData, 2)
```

which outputs:

```
datastr =
  scalar structure containing the fields:
    data: 2x7 float matrix
    t0: 1x1 scalar
MyData =
   39899   43311   46618   46773   42841   40228   35909
   28070   22204   15375   96730  -82862  -79456  -76144

M1 =
   4.2226e+04
  -1.0869e+04
```

which is okay. Even if I create random data with "rand(7, 1360160)" the output is okay. You realy should consider creating a testcase which can be run or upload you data to your webspace and add a link here.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the Short e format. I feel stupid about that right now.

Comment: Ok, I have marked your answer, since it really got me through it. It seems there is something really wrong with the file data (probably it was gathered in a wrong way or saved badly) Anyway, it helped to see, that it was not Octave that failed me.
Thank you again!